# List Updates automatically feed quick links

Tags: list, power-automate, sharepoint-list

Is it possible to make a SharePoint list submissions/updates automatically feed into a quick links / highlighted content web parts?

I have a list open for everyone to submit to. I want the most recent submissions shown on our SharePoint page either through quick links or highlighted content or any other display web part besides the previewed list option.  Is this possible through Power Automate? I am fairly new to Power Automate.

Sorry if I worded this incorrectly and thank you in advanced.

I do not where to begin, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, quick links can only be configured by editing the page and interacting with the quick links web part.

However, you can use a regular SharePoint list with a URL field. Then you can use JSON formatting to add images etc. for the link to display in a list view web part on the home page. The view filtering will determine which items (e.g. last 5) are showing.

There are JSON formatting examples for this scenario just a short google search away. Also, this question on the SharePoint Stackexchange site:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/306794/click-on-image-to-follow-link-json-custom-formatting

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.